# powershell automatic data creation time watch

Tags: powershell

i have a windows server with some hotfolders, all data in the folders will be transfered in a other directory. But sometimes the data stucks in the same folder and the service is still running.

Because of that i wanted to created a powershell script that watch the data creation time and compare it with the actual time. If the difference is more then 10 min send  Mail to me, that i can restart the service.

The script should do loop if he detect a data that isn´t transferred and send only one mail and not a mail for every data.

I tryed it for myself and stuck at this point:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force C:\Ueberwachung
Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -le $CurDate.AddMinutes(-10))}

$PSEmailServer = "192.168.0.11"
ForEach ($file in $Files) {Send-MailMessage -to "luis.jablonski@boyn.eu" -from "PowerShell 
<ps@boyn.eu>" -Subject "Hotfolder Alarm" -body "Dateien werden nicht bearbeitet"

 break
}
```

the script detectet all datas in the folder see:

```
Verzeichnis: C:\Ueberwachung


Mode LastWriteTime Length Name
---- ------------- ------ ----
-a---- 30.04.2021 09:39 0 asdsad.pptx
-a---- 30.04.2021 09:39 0 sadsada.docx
-a---- 30.04.2021 09:39 0 sadsadsadsad.txt
-a---- 28.04.2021 16:03 0 test.txt
```

but doesnt send me a mail, so i think something like my trigger or the compare with the actual time doenst work.

Has anybody a Idea what my Problem ist?

Im glad for every help

Dear Luis

Comment: You're missing a pipe after `Get-ChildItem`. What is in your `$files` variable?

Comment: On Windows you usually need to supply an explicit `-SmtpServer` to `Send-MailMessage` as well

Comment: i tryed the mail message in a seperat script and it worked with this.

Comment: in the     `$files`variable is nothing. i Want with get-childitem that he looks in this folder and looks at all data in there and look for every data the time and copare it with the system time. What do you mean with `pipe`? because the command works it shows me all the data in the folder with the `lastwritetime`

Comment: @l.jablonski Did you test it using the same account as the service is using for logon?

Comment: yes with the sama account

Answer (score 0):

Your script is behaving as I would expect.
`Get-ChildItem` is output to screen as it is not placed into a list (`$Files`).

`$Files` is empty so the loop is never 'looped'.

Issues here:

1. In the line: `ForEach ($file in $Files) {Send-MailMessage`... You
   have not added anything to `$Files`. You could pipe `Get-ChildItem -Force C:\Ueberwachung Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -le $CurDate.AddMinutes(-10))}` to $Files to give the list some data.
   Other wise $Files is empty so there's nothing to loop through and
   therefore, no emails.
2. As mentioned, `Send-MailMessage` needs the param `-smtpserver $PSEmailServer` added, so it knows via which SMTP server to send the
   emails.
3. Last but not least, do you really want an email per file in $Files?
   Perhaps you want to change the code so that the list of $Files is in
   the email body as a whole?
4. Not quite sure why `break` is in there?

Comment: iam a beginner in powershell i askes other people to help me.